# How do I update a table based off the generated index key of an insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm created a temp table with most of the values I need to insert into a set of tables. From this temp table I have all the values I need for the insert to the first table, but the insert to the next table depends on the identity key generated by the insert to the first table.

I could very well just update my temp table after the first insert, but I'd like to try using the output clause.

I want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
<values from temp table>
OUTPUT <update my temp table with generated identity keys>

INSERT INTO Table2
<values from temp table including the output updated id column>
```

Comment: you could always query the primary table with a max(id), iterate it by one and set it as a variable to use later on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you better create another temp table (OR) table type variable and go from there as shown below. Cause I don't think you can update the same temp table from where you are inserting using `output` clause.

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (ID INT not null identity primary key, 
                        TEXTVal VARCHAR(100))

create TABLE #tmp(ID INT, TEXTVal VARCHAR(100))

create TABLE #tmp1(ID INT, TEXTVal VARCHAR(100))

CREATE TABLE TestTable1 (ID INT not null, TEXTVal VARCHAR(100))


INSERT #tmp (ID, TEXTVal)
VALUES (1,'FirstVal')

INSERT #tmp (ID, TEXTVal)
VALUES (2,'SecondVal')


INSERT INTO TestTable (TEXTVal)
OUTPUT Inserted.ID, Inserted.TEXTVal INTO #tmp1
select TEXTVal from #tmp

INSERT INTO TestTable1 (ID, TEXTVal)
select ID, TEXTVal from #tmp1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `merge` your `temptable` into `Table1`, and output the results to a variable table, then insert the original data joined to the variable table into `Table2`.

Example:

```
DECLARE @MyIDs TABLE (TempTableID int NOT NULL, Table1ID int NOT NULL)

MERGE INTO Table1 
USING TempTable AS Tmp
    ON Table1.SomeValue = Tmp.SomeValue
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
    VALUES (tmp.col1, tmp.col2, tmp.col3, tmp.col4, tmp.col5)
OUTPUT Tmp.ID
      ,Table1.ID
INTO @MyIDs;

INSERT INTO Table2 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, Table1ID)
SELECT tmp.col1, tmp.col2, tmp.col3, tmp.col4, tmp.col5, new.Table1ID
FROM TempTable tmp
JOIN @MyIDs new ON tmp.ID = new.TempTableID
```